# Subspace-based generalisation of weak* topology sequential?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $V$ be a normed space and $(V_j)_{j\in [0,1]}$ be a family of linear subspaces of $V$ with $V_1$ non-trivial and such that $V_1\subsetneq V_j\subseteq V_i$ whenever $i\leq j$. We write $W:=V'$ for the topological dual of $V$.

Recall that a net $(\phi_\alpha)\subset W$ is weak* convergent to $\phi\in W$ if $\phi_\alpha(x)\rightarrow^\ast\phi(x)$ for each $x\in V$.

Given the subspaces of $V$, we can weaken this convergence by passing to the restricted pointwise convergence
$$\tag{1}\phi_\alpha\rightarrow^j\phi \quad :\Leftrightarrow \quad \lim_{\alpha}\phi_\alpha(x)=\phi(x) \ \text{ for each } x\in V_j,$$
for any given $j\in[0,1]$. This notion of convergence can be further weakened by defining

$$\tag{2}\phi_\alpha\rightarrow\phi \quad :\Leftrightarrow \quad \phi_\alpha\rightarrow^j\phi \ \ \text{ for some } \ 0\leq j < 1.$$

**Question:** Do you know if the (notion of) convergence $(2)$ defines a sequential topology?